# Building Sphinx with sphinx_book_theme

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I'm trying to use Sphinx with [Sphinx book theme](https://sphinx-book-theme.readthedocs.io/) in my documentation but I'm having problems building the docs.

### Setup

I installed Sphinx and the theme and initiated the docs with:

```
pip install sphinx
pip install sphinx_book_theme
sphinx-quickstart
```

Then I changed the theme to Sphinx book theme [as described in the docs](https://sphinx-book-theme.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorials/get-started.html) by adding the extension and changing the HTML theme in the `conf.py`.

My `conf.py` looks like this (removed autogenerated comments):

```
# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = 'mytest'
copyright = '2022, Me'
author = 'Me'
release = '0.1.0'


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

extensions = [
    'sphinx_book_theme' # I changed this
]
templates_path = ['_templates']
language = 'python'
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

html_theme = 'sphinx_book_theme' # I changed this
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

### Building

However, when I try to build the docs:

```
sphinx-build docs . _build/html
```

I get this error:

```
Running Sphinx v4.5.0
loading translations [python]... not available for built-in messages
building [mo]: targets for 0 po files that are out of date
building [html]: targets for 1 source files that are out of date
updating environment: [new config] 1 added, 0 changed, 0 removed
reading sources... [100%] index
looking for now-outdated files... none found
pickling environment... done
checking consistency... done
preparing documents... done
writing output... [100%] index
Theme error:
An error happened in rendering the page index.
Reason: TemplateNotFound('sidebar-logo.html')
```

How do I fix this and use the book theme? Do I need to create a sidebar template? If so, how and where? I don't have a logo for my project and would not like to create one at this moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself. It seems if you remove the line `templates_path = ['_templates']` it works:

```
# -- Project information -----------------------------------------------------

project = 'mytest'
copyright = '2022, Me'
author = 'Me'
release = '0.1.0'


# -- General configuration ---------------------------------------------------

extensions = [
    'sphinx_book_theme'
]
# templates_path = ['_templates'] # REMOVE THIS LINE TO WORK
language = 'python'
exclude_patterns = ['_build', 'Thumbs.db', '.DS_Store']


# -- Options for HTML output -------------------------------------------------

html_theme = 'sphinx_book_theme'
html_static_path = ['_static']
```

If you have something in the `templates`, I suspect you need to create the `sidebar-logo.html` here. Not sure how though.

Comment: See [PR #768](https://github.com/executablebooks/sphinx-book-theme/issues/768) for root cause behind issue with using `templates_path`.